# Unable to backup my app database

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I have following code:

**MyBackupPlace**

```
public class MyBackupPlace extends BackupAgentHelper {
    static final String FILES_BACKUP_KEY = "myfiles";

    // Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        DbBackupHelper helper = new DbBackupHelper(this, DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
        addHelper(FILES_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
    }

    /**
     * We want to ensure that the UI is not trying to rewrite the data file
     * while we're reading it for backup, so we override this method to
     * supply the necessary locking.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
                         ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("onBackup");
        synchronized (MainActivity.sDataLock) {
            super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adding locking around the file rewrite that happens during restore is
     * similarly straightforward.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
                          ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        synchronized (MainActivity.sDataLock) {
            System.out.println("onRestore");
            super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
        }
    }
}
```

**DBBackupHelper**

```
public class DbBackupHelper extends FileBackupHelper {

    public DbBackupHelper(Context ctx, String dbName) {
        super(ctx, ctx.getDatabasePath(dbName).getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

**DBHelper**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "testDB.db";
    ....
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupAgent="MyBackupPlace"
    android:restoreAnyVersion="true">
    ...    
</activity

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
    android:value="..." />
```

I get the Backup key from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/backup/signup.html).

Then I tried to run:

> adb shell bmgr transport
>   com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
>
> adb shell bmgr backupnow my_package_name

it returns me:

```
Running backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Transport error
Backup finished with result: Transport error
```

while if I use other transport:

> adb shell bmgr transport
>   android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
>
> adb shell bmgr backupnow my_package_name

it returns me:

```
Running backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Success
Backup finished with result: Backup is not allowed
```

What could be wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Well I need to enable some Settings at my device:

> Settings > Back up my data

Comment: In my case (Xiaomi Android 10): Settings > Accounts & Sync > Auto-Sync data

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a test device, it's likely "Backup" is not enabled. For example, this is the default setting of "Android System Settings -> Backup" of an emulator.

To enable it, you will have to log in with a Google Account (because back-up data is stored in Google Drive for each user). I just ended up using my personal phone to do the testing instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved disabling **High protection** (cryptography) like in the attached image:

[image]